# Get posted value to action page via Java Script

Tags: javascript, php, forms

How to Get posted value to action page via Java Script?

**test.php:**

```
<form action="/shop/cart.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="300"/>
    <div name="mysubmitbutton" id="mysubmitbutton" class="customButton" onclick="this.parentNode.submit()">
        Button Text
    </div>
</form>
```

**cart.php:**

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['mysubmitbutton'])){
      echo (int)$_POST['price']; 
    }
?>
```

But there isn't any output in cart.php because I sent with javascript, Then how to Get value 300 and echo in cart.php ?

Comment: because, div's aren't valid form inputs. look at your console and enable error reporting.

Comment: and why use js and not a regular submit button?

Comment: because I had a button with button type and then there isn't any way to pass value to card php?

Comment: you'd need to use ajax for this

Comment: I need just pass a hidden value to cart.php with js or ajax, but I don't know how to pass

Comment: You use a `<button>` and not a `<div>`.

Comment: putting the price on the client side is crazy by the way, i could change that to **1** and submit it

Comment: Because I don't want add submit type, my type is button

Comment: YOU DON'T HAVE A BUTTON.

Comment: @miken32 the submission still works and posts. Is just `$_POST['mysubmitbutton']` what isn't set. He should check for `$_POST['price']`

Comment: @msg I'm well aware of that. But they keep commenting that there is a button when there is not. And they were told that in the very first comment.

Comment: we have "button|submit|reset type, my type is button, is there any way to get 300 in cart page? security is not important for me.

Comment: If it walks as a duck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The submission works, but the `div` not being a form element, the value is not being sent so is never entering the `if` block. Change your php to:

```
if(isset($_POST['price'])){
  echo (int)$_POST['price']; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is executed on server while JS - in browser. What you need is:

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.currentTarget.querySelector('[name="price"]').value);
})
```

Comment: No. You should put is at the end of test.php inside of `script` tag